# Get DISTINCT nearest neighbors with indexed search

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I'm using the indexed nearest neighbor search to return the closest points to a given starting location. My points also have attributes like color and shape, stored as strings. I want each query to only return the closest point for each type of point.

So if my points were, in order of distance to my starting location:

- red square
- red square
- red circle
- orange square
- blue circle

The query for the four closest points would return:

- the closest red square
- red circle
- orange square
- blue circle

I tried using `DISTINCT` but it's asking to give the `DISTINCT` column in the `ORDER BY` and  I haven't had success in doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice quick solution,

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT color_column, shape_column FROM table_name GROUP BY color_column, shape_column
)
SELECT 
  c.color_column, 
  c.shape_column,
  (
   SELECT other_column 
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE 
      color_column = c.color_column AND
      shape_column = c.shape_column 
   ORDER BY the_geom <-> starting_geom 
   LIMIT 1
  ) other  
FROM c
```

Comment: Thanks. That'll get me results for distinct colors but I'm interested in getting distinct color and shape combinations. I've edited the question to flesh out that distinction with the `red circle` example. I tried adding a second `WITH` clause and an `AND` to the conditional but I get `syntax error near c`. I'm confused as to how `c` is getting defined.

Comment: I've edited my result. You can group by whatever number of columns you want distinct answers for. The 'c' alias was from something like "SELECT * FROM table_name c", where I aliased the table name, I've removed it just to avoid confusion.